# Nmap port closing

Tags: shell, iptables, nmap, quoting

I am trying to close unused ports using Nmap in a shell script. If I hard code the port number the shell script works fine but I want to pass on a variable to the command where the variable contains the port number.

Example: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port $portNumber -j DROP

```
Error:Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
' specified.4.21: invalid port/service `4345  
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Note : 4345 was the value assigned to portNumber & in the error portNumber appears as `4345

Comment: Looks like you're failing to strip some quote characters off your portNumber variable somewhere...